# Simple equation reversal

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am solving follwoing challenge but unable to do so now since last 4 hrs and I am stuck :

> Challenge :

```
> Given a mathematical equation that has *,+,-,/, reverse it as follows:
> 
> solve("100*b/y") = "y/b*100" 
> solve("a+b-c/d*30") = "30*d/c-b+a"
```

**Code I have made to resolve the challenge**

```
def solve(s):
    a,b = s.split('/')
    return (b+"/"+a)
```

**expected output:**
'y/b*100'

**observed output:**
'y/100*b'

please need your kind help in resolving this issue :

Best Regards,
Diwakar

Comment: Split `a` on `*` and reverse the result.

Comment: Relevant [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5aa3af22ba1bb5209f000037) on Codewars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation of `solve` function that can reverse the equation.

```
def solve(equation):
    parts = []
    operand = ""
    for ch in equation:
        if ch in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
            parts.append(operand)
            parts.append(ch)
            operand = ""
        else:
            operand += ch
    if operand:
        parts.append(operand)

    return "".join(parts[::-1])
```

print(solve(equation))

The solve function works by separating the parts (operators ["+", "-", "*", "/"] and operands [numbers, variables etc]) into a list.
For eg. "a+b-c/d*30" becomes ["a", "+", "b", "-", "c", "/", "d" , "*", "30"]. Reverse and join the list to get the final solution.

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
def solve(s):              #Hardest part of this problem is to handle NUMBERS.
    li = [s[0]]            # the first element of s,such as "1"
    for i in range(1,len(s)): # begin to handle the rest of s
        if li[-1].isdigit() and s[i].isdigit():  # if the last element of li is digit and the current element of s is also digit,then they belong to a same NUMBER. 
            li[-1] = li[-1] + s[i]
        else:
            li.append(s[i])
    return "".join(li[::-1])
```

this will work,wish it will help you

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: The most difficult part of this problem lies in the processing of numbers. For example, if 300 is output directly in reverse order, it will become 003, which is wrong.

Comment: After using the split method, if there are consecutive digits, they belong to the same number. This is the core of the algorithm

Comment: Wish that helpful~

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no parentheses and the input is well-formed, one approach is to use a regex with alternation--one side of the alternation to match all operators, the other to match all non-operators (variables and literals). Reverse and join.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "a+b-c/d*30"
>>> "".join(re.findall(r"[*/+-]+|[^*/+-]+", s)[::-1])
'30*d/c-b+a'
```